# Passing Component as Props shows error: Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have a component named **EditForm** which I imported in another component called **ProductList.** **I need to pass EditForm component from ProductList to another component ListContainer as props and render it (EditForm) inside ListContainer.** The flow is given below for better understanding:

```
// EditForm.js

const EditForm = () => {...}
export default EditForm

// ProductList.js

import EditForm from "./EditForm"
..
<ListContainer editForm={EditForm} /> // pass the editform as props

// ListContainer.js

const ListContainer({editForm: EditForm}) => {
    ...
    <EditForm /> // use editform here
}
```

Here is my code below:

***ProductList.js***

```
import React from "react"
import ListContainer from "../common/ListContainer";
import EditForm from "./EditForm";

const ef = () => {
    return (<EditForm />)
}

const ProductList = () => {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <ListContainer  ef={ef} />
        </React.Fragment >
    )
}

export default ProductList
```

***ListContainer.js***

```
import React, { useState } from "react"

const ListContainer = ({ ef: EditComponent }) => {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
                <EditComponent />
        </React.Fragment >
    )
}

export default ListContainer
```

error:
[image]

**FULL CODE LINK: https://onecompiler.com/javascript/3yfvnyyf4**

Comment: Shouldn't be `import { EditForm } from "./EditForm"`?

Comment: EditForm is default export. Also it shows as function inside productlist and listcontainer

Comment: How is it the default export when you export it without the `default` keyword?

Comment: kindly check the full code link I added in description: https://onecompiler.com/javascript/3yfvnyyf4

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass a component down for the child to render it. The proper react way of doing it would be to pass it as props.children

For Example:

```
import React from "react"
import ListContainer from "../common/ListContainer";
import EditForm from "./EditForm";



const ProductList = () => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <ListContainer>
           <EditForm/>
        </ListContainer>
    </React.Fragment >
)
}

export default ProductList
```

You can access the children in your list container like this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react"

const ListContainer = ({ children }) => {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
                <children />
        </React.Fragment >
    )
}

export default ListContainer
```

However if you want to pass it as a prop as you requested then the correct syntax for that is:

```
<React.Fragment>
   <ListContainer  ef={EditForm} />
</React.Fragment >
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: kindly check the full code link I added in description: https://onecompiler.com/javascript/3yfvnyyf4

Comment: @WahidulAlam  check this link, it works!, however my syntax was a little bit incorrect which I have fixed in this edit. https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-snowflake-r33v4z?file=/src/ProductList.jsx

Answer (score 0):

React js have have Higher order component concept for dealing these type of scenarios https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html#:~:text=A%20higher%2Dorder%20component%20(HOC,and%20returns%20a%20new%20component.

Answer (score 0):

Althout it's better to pass child component as props.children, but your code should works if you already uses 'export default'. Myabe you could check the props by debugging and find if there is any typo.

Comment: Yes the EditForm is export default and in console.log it shows the function. However it's not working.

Comment: Where did you put your console.log? it's better to put more real code here. I tried your demo code and it works well.

Comment: i have added full code link in description: https://onecompiler.com/javascript/3yfvnyyf4

Comment: In ProductList.js change  <ListContainer item={item} ef={< EditForm/>} /> to: <ListContainer item={item} ef={ EditForm } />

Comment: tried : <ListContainer item={item} ef={ EditForm } /> but no luck !! I request you kindly look at full code. so that if you could find something.

Comment: please see this in sandbox: [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-zhukovsky-yoliyo?file=/src/ProductList.jsx)

Comment: it works if you have single props. I had two props, hence getting issues. now fine. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved the problem by doing the following in **ListContainer.js**

```
import React from "react"

const ListContainer = (props) => {

// need to use children.types to catch the component in child element

const Edit = props.children.type 

return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Edit />
        </React.Fragment >
    )
}

export default ListContainer
```

**ProductList.js (same as before)**

```
import React from "react"
import ListContainer from "../common/ListContainer";
import EditForm from "./EditForm";



const ProductList = () => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <ListContainer>
           <EditForm/>
        </ListContainer>
    </React.Fragment >
)
}

export default ProductList
```